# Card Game using c++ ai engine and ASP.NET C# pages

Tags: c++, asp.net, c#-4.0, game-engine, playing-cards

I have a project to build a card game using C# ASP.NET, the project is to have a card games website where users play and challenge each others.

My friend can build the AI engine using C++, but how I can communicate with that engine through c# specially it should be an browser based online game.

Everything from pages, scripts and site system is easy to implement in C#, but the cards table for each game (the communication with the engine) is something that I cant figure.

Which approach to use, Is there any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to mix C# with C++, then probably the easiest way to communicate is to create a C++ DLL which includes a C interface. You can then import this DLL using [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=VS.71%29.aspx):

```
[DllImport("ai.dll")]
static extern int doSomething(int numCardOnTable, int[] cardOnTable,
  int numCardsOnHand, int[] cardsOnHand, out int cardToPlay);
```

Another way is to use Managed C++ which you can directly import in C#:

```
namespace CPP_managed_code
{
  public ref class AI
  {
  public:
    int doSomething(int numCardOnTable, int[] cardOnTable, int numCardsOnHand,
      int[] cardsOnHand, out int cardToPlay)
    {
      // ...
      return 0;
    }
  };
}
```

And your C# code:

```
using CPP_managed_code;

// ...
  unsafe private void myCSharpMethod()
  {
    AI ai = new AI();
    ai.doSomething(/*...*/);
  }
```

But I'd not recommend using Managed C++ because it is not standard C++.